# How can you edit multiple legend boxes in a seanborn scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, legend

I want to rename and move the two legends. I want the top legend to be outside of the graph, upper right, and titled `'Average Cost'`. I want the second legend to be outside the graph, bottom right, and titled `'Total Revenue'`

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = sns.scatterplot(
        x=top_rev_mean['cost_of_the_order_y'],
        y='cost_of_the_order_x', 
        data=top_rev_mean, 
        size = "cost_of_the_order_x", 
        hue='cost_of_the_order_y'
    )
plt.ylabel('Total Order Revenue')
plt.xlabel('Average Order Cost Per Cuisine')
plt.show()
```

[image: Cost Scatter]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are working with a dataframe like this one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


N = 15
top_rev_mean = pd.DataFrame({'cost_of_the_order_y': 17.6 + 4*np.random.random(N),
                             'cost_of_the_order_x': 500 + 2000*np.random.random(N)})
```

```
    cost_of_the_order_y  cost_of_the_order_x
0             19.098160           866.809020
1             21.402857          1108.484486
2             20.527976          1549.512863
3             19.994634          1363.890037
4             18.224075          1082.458280
5             18.223978          1723.705789
6             17.832334           778.987721
7             21.064705          1084.289297
8             20.004460          1232.723687
9             20.432290          1412.139968
10            17.682338          2070.351923
11            21.479639           899.347564
12            20.929771          1528.468877
13            18.449356          1684.829138
14            18.327300           592.900825
```

When you set up the scatterplot, you have to be sure the legend is drawn, in order to get handles and labels later, so you need to pass `legend = True` parameter to [**`seaborn.scatterplot`**](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = top_rev_mean, x = 'cost_of_the_order_y', y = 'cost_of_the_order_x', size = "cost_of_the_order_x", hue = 'cost_of_the_order_y', legend = True)
```

Then you can extract handles and labels of current legend with [**`ax.get_legend_handles_labels`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html):

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

Now you need to split elements of the first legend from elements of the second one:

```
legend1 = {}
legend2 = {}
titles = {}

for handle, label in zip(handles, labels):
    if label.replace('.', '').isdigit() == False:
        titles[handle] = label
    else:
        if len(list(titles.keys())) == 1:
            legend1[handle] = label
        else:
            legend2[handle] = label
```

Finally, you can remove the legend drawn from seaborn and draw the two legend you want:

```
ax.legend().remove()

upper_legend = ax.legend(handles = list(legend1.keys()), labels = list(legend1.values()), title = 'Average Cost', loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1))
ax.add_artist(upper_legend)
lower_legend = ax.legend(handles = list(legend2.keys()), labels = list(legend2.values()), title = 'Total Revenue', loc = 'lower left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0))
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


N = 15
top_rev_mean = pd.DataFrame({'cost_of_the_order_y': 17.6 + 4*np.random.random(N),
                             'cost_of_the_order_x': 500 + 2000*np.random.random(N)})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

sns.scatterplot(ax = ax, data = top_rev_mean, x = 'cost_of_the_order_y', y = 'cost_of_the_order_x', size = "cost_of_the_order_x", hue = 'cost_of_the_order_y', legend = True)

handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

legend1 = {}
legend2 = {}
titles = {}

for handle, label in zip(handles, labels):
    if label.replace('.', '').isdigit() == False:
        titles[handle] = label
    else:
        if len(list(titles.keys())) == 1:
            legend1[handle] = label
        else:
            legend2[handle] = label


ax.legend().remove()

upper_legend = ax.legend(handles = list(legend1.keys()), labels = list(legend1.values()), title = 'Average Cost', loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1))
ax.add_artist(upper_legend)
lower_legend = ax.legend(handles = list(legend2.keys()), labels = list(legend2.values()), title = 'Total Revenue', loc = 'lower left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 0))

ax.set_ylabel('Total Order Revenue')
ax.set_xlabel('Average Order Cost Per Cuisine')

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!